# Pass a queryset as the argument to __in in django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a list of object ID's that I am getting from a query in an model's method, then I'm using that list to delete objects from a different model:

```
class SomeObject(models.Model):
    # [...]
    def do_stuff(self, some_param):
        # [...]
        ids_to_delete = {item.id for item in self.items.all()}
        other_object = OtherObject.objects.get_or_create(some_param=some_param)
        other_object.items.filter(item_id__in=ids_to_delete).delete()
```

What I don't like is that this takes 2 queries (well, technically 3 for the `get_or_create()` but in the real code it's actually `.filter(some_param=some_param).first()` instead of the `.get()`, so I don't think there's any easy way around that).

How do I pass in an unevaluated queryset as the argument to an `__in` lookup?

I would like to do something like:

```
ids_to_delete = self.items.all().values("id")
other_object.items.filter(item_id__in=ids_to_delete).delete()
```

Comment: Can you share the model of `OtherObject` and `items`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think that will help you answer my question, it's a general question about how I can use an un-evaluated queryset for `__in`

Comment: well here the `.delete()` will *delete* `Item`s, not its relation to these items (so `.remove()`). This might not be the intended effect, since you could have done that with `self.items.all().delete()` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can, pass a `QuerySet` to the query:

```
other_object.items.filter(id__in=self.items.all()).delete()
```

this will transform it in a subquery. But not all databases, especially MySQL ones, are good with such subqueries. Furthermore Django handles `.delete()` *manually*. It will thus make a query to fetch the primary keys of the items, and then trigger the delete logic (and also remove items that have a `CASCADE` dependency). So `.delete()` is not done as one query, but at least two queries, and often a larger amount due to `ForeignKey`s with an `on_delete` trigger.

Note however that you here *remove* `Item` objects, not "unlink" this from the `other_object`. For this [**`.remove(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I should've tried the code sample I posted, you can in fact do this. It's given as an example in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in), but it says "be cautious about using nested queries and understand your database server’s performance characteristics" and recommends against doing this, casting the subquery into a list:

```
values = Blog.objects.filter(
        name__contains='Cheddar').values_list('pk', flat=True)
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__in=list(values))
```

Comment: It all depends: casting into a list can sometimes dramatically improve overall performance, even though it does an extra query. I've seen queries perform three orders of magnitude slower when a complex subquery is used. Generally, I leave as a subquery, and if I notice performance issues, I convert to a list (and comment why).